# calling QgsDataSourceUri with QGIS for python plugin

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

TLDR : using QGIS, I'm trying to develop a python plugin to update a database. Unfortunately I get immediatly an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'QgsDataSourceUri' is not defined

More detailed:

I work on QGIS2.18 to develop a plugin to update some data located on a postgres database.
for this, I want to use this kind of code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceURI

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()

# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection(hote_IP, "5432", base_de_donnee, utilisateur,     mot_de_passe)
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally
# subset (WHERE clause)
#uri.setDataSource("public", "roads", "the_geom", "cityid = 2643")

uri.setDataSource("", sql, "geom", "", "gid")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), zapm, "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

(I got the code from the net, I'll adapt it later on)

My problem : when I try to run this code on the Python console of QGIS, I immediatly get the error

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'QgsDataSourceUri' is not defined*

even when I only run the import and the line *uri = QgsDataSourceUri()*, I get the same error message.

I have not been able to find out how to correct this issue.

problem of installation of QGIS? of python? bad imports?

Config:
qgis 2.18.20
python 3.6.5

If anyone has an idea on how to solve this, I would be really glad.

Thanks,
Erwann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply are using the wrong class name. It should be `uri = QgsDataSourceURI()` instead of `uri = QgsDataSourceUri()` because you've imported `QgsDataSourceURI` and not `QgsDataSourceUri`

QGIS and QT Python classes are case-sensitive. You can confirm the exact syntax looking at [QGIS 2.18 related API](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsDataSourceURI.html).

Comment: aaahhh, I kept looking and did not think about that...
Thanks a lot :)